# jsdoc - How to use Express.js Request and Response as param types

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jsdoc

I have a function which takes as arguments Express Request and Response objects.

```
function doStuff(req, res) {
  // do something
}
```

How to use jsdoc to document the types of `req` and `res`?

EDIT: The reasons I feel this is not a duplicate is that I am asking how to specifically use the Express classes as the types, where as the other questions suggest documenting it as `Object` and then documenting the properties

Answer (score 4):

You can not only JsDoc the parameter types and descriptions, and but also their expected members.

```
/**
 * 
 * @module doStuff
 * @function
 * @param req {Object} The request.
 * @param res {Object} The response.
 * @param req.params.foo {String} The foo param.
 * @param req.query.bar {String} The bar query.
 * @param req.body {Object} The JSON payload.
 * @param {Function} next
 * @return {undefined}
 */
function doStuff(req, res, next){
}
```